# EOF error in Python using raw_input

Tags: python-2.7

```
z=list()
t=raw_input()
for i in range (0,int(t)):
    x= raw_input()
    z.append(x)
for i in z:
    if(i%3==0 and i%5==0):
        print 'FizzBuzz'
    elif(i%3==0):
        print 'Fizz'
    elif(i%5==0):
        print 'Buzz'
    else:
        print i
    print '\n'
```

This is my code. For some reason i keep getting this error

> Traceback (most recent call last):    File
>   "/tmp/editor_trsource_1390938776_887424.py", line 10, in
>       x= raw_input()  EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Comment: How are you running it?

Comment: What environment? What shell? What are you actually typing as input?

Comment: Windows, t is 2. And couldnt get to x.

Comment: You forget to convert ``x`` to int. Other than that, your code runs fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

`z.append(x)` should be `z += [int(x)]`: you need to convert the strings to integers before checking their divisibility.

```
z=list()
t=raw_input()
for i in range (0,int(t)):
    x= raw_input()
    z += [int(x)]
for i in z:
    if(i%3==0 and i%5==0):
        print 'FizzBuzz'
    elif(i%3==0):
        print 'Fizz'
    elif(i%5==0):
        print 'Buzz'
    else:
        print i
    print '\n'
```